# how could i pass two props from jsx to scss

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have following two props that i need to access in linear-gradient in `MyComponent.scss`

```
startColor: PropTypes.string
endColor: PropTypes.string
```

My component looks like below

```
MyComponent.jsx

<myComponent 
  {...customProps}
  style={{color: customProps.color }}
  className={classess}
  ...other props here..
  />
```

Currently it accepts only one color.

linear-gradient property in `MyComponent.scss` looks like below

```
linear-gradient(to left, currentcolor, currentcolor);
```

It'll be updated to use startColor and endColor.

How could i achieve that?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: You should use inline styles or some CSS in JS solution like [Styled Components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass props to SCSS, but [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) supports that. See [Adapting based on props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) from its documentation.

Without styled-components, the only other option is using inline styles by passing a `style` prop to the element.

Comment: styled-components is a great library. +1

Comment: Agreed, one of my first additional libraries in pretty much any React project. :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how could i use inline style for both prop?

Comment: Sure, you could do `style={{ background: \`linear-gradient(to left, ${props.startColor}, ${props.endColor})\` }}`

Comment: I see. The problem is myComponent is a progress bar and this will apply linear gradient to all progress bars and in scss i am not doing linear-gradient to classes having value = 100 (fully loaded progress bars)

Comment: @DominikJanković so i added this style `      style={{ color: customProps.color,
        background: `linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgba(255,255,255,.5)),
                 linear-gradient(to left, ${customProps.color}, ${customProps.color})` }}` Not passing startColor and endColor yet. just trying to apply the gradient on same color but it doent apply gradient. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can have multiple linear-gradients defined in the background prop. What are you trying to do? I made a simple CodePen so compare it with what you have: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRzJLP?&editors=0010

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with inline CSS or using a CSS Object in a JS file. But not directly in a file that is interpreted as CSS specifically.

TECHNICALLY, you could achieve this using server side rendering, requiring express to overwrite a file in the file system and return the style. But that's insane, and dumb, and insane.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can easily get props in scss from jsx
is send props as a data-text(item) and in scss i get this :
content: attr(data-text);

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is actually possible using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames). An instance is a boolean to the className in the JSX, then utilize it in scss.

The classnames function takes any number of arguments which can be a string or an object. The argument 'styles.wrapper' is a string corresponding to a CSS class defined in your styles file.

The next argument is an object. The keys of the object are CSS classes and the values are conditions that determine whether these classes should be applied.

In this case, the styles['available-button'] class will be applied if isAvailable is false (!isAvailable). This could be used to apply certain styles when the component is not in an available state.

Similarly, the styles['disabled-button'] class will be applied if isDisabled is truthy. This means that if isDisabled has a value other than false, 0, null, undefined, NaN, or an empty string (""), the styles['disabled-button'] class will be applied. This could be used to apply certain styles when isDisabled is defined.

The classnames function will return a string with the classes that meet their respective conditions. This string is then assigned to the className prop of the component, which applies the corresponding styles.

```html
<button
  className={classnames(styles.wrapper, {
    [styles['available-button']]: !isAvailable,
    [styles['disabled-button']]: isDisabled,
  })}
 >Delete</button>
```

while the scss:

```css
button.wrapper.wrapper {
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.remove-button {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

button.available-button.available-button {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

button.remove-button.remove-button {
  display: none;
}
```